# 2 exact same HTML page renders differently depending on hosting

Tags: html, css, svg, resize, rendering

I've got 2 exact same site (one on my dev server, and one on my prod server), but the 2 pages renders differently... And it's not a browser issue since all they all do the same render:
the SVG background scales as it should only my dev server ...

dev server: http://clients.ntasky.com/MA/V1.1/#/about/history

prod server: http://mamobilieractuel.com/V1.1/#/about/history

I've overrided the CSS inline to force the SVG to take all the space.

```
background-size: cover !important;
```

Is it a correct way of doing it ?

I really would appreciate some help.
Thanks by advance

Comment: The two SVG files are different.

Comment: thank you so much... i must be very tired :) +1 @Blender

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.svg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Do not set size on your image. You can apply this CSS to your 'body' element or any container inside.